# MySql table column deleted its AI flag when I altered the size of the column from BIGINT(11) to BIGINT(20)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table name file_upload
It has column upload_id as BIGINT(11) AI PK NOT NULL
when I altered the tables column size to BIGINT(20) the AI flag got deleted, 
Should I provide the new definition to the column everytime I alter anything from the column?

Comment: Yes you will require to add AI, "alter table YourTable MODIFY column Id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"; This will only be required when modifying the AUTO_INCREMENT column. As soon as you change the datatype except primary key and Not Null checkbox remains same an AI gets unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Only a little note. There is no real difference between **BIGINT(10)** and **BIGINT(20)**. You can store always the same values. The size if only use with **ZEROFILL**.

See my Sample

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `bigints` (
    ->   `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `bigint1` BIGINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `bigint10` BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `bigint20` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,04 sec)

mysql>
mysql> INSERT INTO `bigints` (`id`, `bigint1`, `bigint10`, `bigint20`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     (1, 1, 1, 1),
    ->     (2, 100, 100, 100),
    ->     (3, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000),
    ->     (4, 18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551615);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0,01 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * from bigints;
+----+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| id | bigint1              | bigint10             | bigint20             |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|  1 |                    1 |           0000000001 | 00000000000000000001 |
|  2 |                  100 |           0000000100 | 00000000000000000100 |
|  3 |           1000000000 |           1000000000 | 00000000001000000000 |
|  4 | 18446744073709551615 | 18446744073709551615 | 18446744073709551615 |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0,01 sec)

mysql>
```